# CPU running slower than normal - and hotter

Tags: performance, cpu, heatsink

Some liquid got spilled on my PC. I cleaned it up but when trying to turn it on I noticed that there were some drops of water on the CPU (AMD). The PC wouldn't turn on - it would start up, but nothing on the screens.

I took the HeatSink off my CPU and took the chip out - and got all the water out of it.

I put it all back together and it's working somewhat fine... however I'm noticing that it's not as fast.

It's getting up to 95c when playing a game, and Windows is telling me that my PC isn't fast enough for Windows 10 (needs to be over 1000mzh).

my CPU is an [AMD Phenom II X4 975 Processor](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103923)

I never replaced the membrane between the CPU and the heatsink - I left it on. Is this a problem?

Open hardware monitor shows that my CPU is running on all cores at 600-3592MHz, but when I play a game my tempurature will rise to 95c-100c. If I turn a movie on at the same time I'm playing a game, and say have an android emulator on, the PC will just turn off.

Could this be because of the heatsink thermal membrane?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of liquid was spilled on your PC? When you take the heat sink off the CPU, if it hasn't been removed in a while, I would HIGHLY recommend that you clean off the old thermal compound with some isopropyl alcohol, and apply fresh thermal compound. I'm not saying that this will fix your issue because there is no telling what other items may have been touched by the water. liquid and electronics typically don't mix well, specifically while running.

The best thing to do in future instances is to dry off the electronics as best as possible. I would clean them with isopropyl alcohol, then still let it sit for maybe a couple days. A fan would definitely help. Running the machine without giving them a lot of time could cause additional damage.

Comment: It was water that was spilled. But could the thermal pad that was broken be the cause of this?

Comment: Old thermal compound could definitely be contributing to the issue since the thermal compound is not able to transfer heat as efficiently since it is old thermal compound. I think it is definitely worth a try since it is a cheap troubleshooting attempt. Make sure you clean the processor and heat sink very well with the isopropyl alcohol wipe, then put some fresh thermal compound on it. I prefer to make a small ball in the middle of the processor, put the heat sink on, then remove the heat sink to ensure I put just the right amount on. YouTube it if you haven't done it before just to be sure.

Answer (score -2):

Check if no short circuits.
Let it dry and cool down.
Use a soft brush like make-up drush to clean off.

Is still slower than normal. Go to a technician!

Comment: How can he safely "Check if no short circuits"?

Comment: I did build the machine myself. Short circuits would burn / smoke or leave a mark on the main board.  I'll try to replace the thermal compound and see if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your post needs to be expanded. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes specific instructions (not just links to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to add detail explaining your solution.